# Does the friend function have to be in the same file?

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, protected, access-specifier

I am actually testing a file and I have a situation, where I need to access some of the protected members of the class from main.cpp. I tried to add, `main()` as friend, didn't work out and learned that it wont work, so I moved everything in the `main()` to a `test ()` and made the `test()` as friend. still it shows the error.

Example would be

```
 //--File.hpp

 namespace Files {

 class File {
          public:
                File(long word_):word(word_) {}
          protected:
                long word;
          private:
                friend int test();
 };
 }//ns:Files


 //--List_File.hpp

 namespace Files {
 class List_File :public File {
         public:
               List_File() : File(sizeof(int) + sizeof(long)) {}
         private:
              friend int test();
 };  
 }//ns:Files 



//--main.cpp

  using namespace Files;

  int test() {

       File *pd = new List_File();
       assert(pd->word == 12); //LINE 34
       return 0;
  }

  int main() {
       test();
       return 0;
  }
```

//it says error on Line 34: Base::value is protected. Please advice.

```
    g++ -O -Wall -Wno-unused -o a.out File.cpp List_File.cpp Data_File.cpp               
    Free_List_File.cpp main.cpp
    File.hpp: In function ‘int test()’:
    File.hpp:30:7: error: ‘long int Files::File::word’ is protected
    main.cpp:34:16: error: within this context
    make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

Comment: The posted code compiled fine for me (under G++ 4.2), after I modified the Derived class declaration (it should say "class Derived : public Base", but the ": public Base" is missing)

Comment: yeah yeah public base is there.. I will check again.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It is strange the above code snippet issues the same error when compiled with my g++ 4.4.5. Is it something related to namespace? I mean maybe you should implement `test` in namespace `Files`. Can't find a sound reference, so just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it definitely doesn't have to be in the same file, but it obviously has to "know" what the class is, i.e.: the header that has the class definition should be included in the file where the function is implemented. Your code should be fine, as commented.

**after you added some context**

Your `test` function is not in the `Files` namespace. If you want it to be in the global context, you should treat it as "`::test`" within the namespace, otherwise the compiler might expect the "`Files::test`" to be the friend function, and not the "`::test`" as in your case. Can't find the formal standard reference, but I'm pretty sure that's the case. Note that you're performing a forward declaration here, so there's no default fall-back to the upper level of scope for name resolution.

Comment: Yeah, exactly thats waht I thought. Not quite sure, why its showing the error. Will get back here soon, to see if anything else is preventing from accessing

Comment: @howtechstuffworks would be nice of you to actually quote the error:-)

Comment: Will namespace affect anything? Because, I could access the public variables though. Or else, Do I need to mention the access specifier under the particular protected or anything?

Comment: @howtechstuffworks definitely. Why don't you reproduce your problem in a small piece of code, and then post it as is so that we could see the problem? the code you posted is fine, you obviously have something else (BTW: I'm assuming main.cpp includes Derived.hpp, and Derived.hpp includes Base.hpp, but you would have other problems if it wasn't so).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missing inheritance declaration in Derived class?

```
 class Derived : public Base {
```

I've tested your code (with inheritance declaration included) and it produced no error

Comment: Nope, I hand typed this code, since my code is too large...... But Not sure why it does the error here...

Answer (score 0):

littedev is right!!
Updated the code according to the comments by littedev..

```
//--File.hpp   
namespace Files {   
    class File {
        public:
            File(long word_):word(word_) {}
        protected:
            long word;
        private:
            friend int test();
    };  
}//ns:Files    

//--List_File.hpp   

namespace Files {
    class List_File :public File {
        public:
            List_File() : File(sizeof(int) + sizeof(long)) {}          \
        private:
            friend int test();  
    };    
}//ns:Files     

//--main.cpp    

namespace Files{    
    int test() {         
        File *pd = new List_File();
        assert(pd->word == 12); //LINE 34
        return 0;
    }

    int main() {
        Files::test();
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that you are trying to access a protected variable outside of the scope of the Files class definition. I would recommend a function that returns the variable word when it is called and use that instead of trying to access a protected variable outside of a class definition. I could be wrong in that I am not really sure what is the scope of a protected variable (whether it is limited only to class declarations or whether it can be accessed outside of the class definition) but I am pretty sure that I am right because protected variables are like private variables. They are only accessible within the class scope. Correct me if I am wrong.

EDIT: Oh I am sorry I didn't realize what you were doing. littleadv is right, your function declaration isn't within the files namespace.

Comment: Yeah You are right, protected and private variables are accessible only inside class, but whats the point of friend function then. I am using it still I am getting an error. Let me see. I did exactly what you said, but will try the same scenario again and debug, once I finish this assignment, will update u guys